# Update Value In JSON File With Python

Tags: python, json

How do I enter a json file and find `"class": "DepictionScreenshotsView"` and replace it with `"class": ""`? Any help will be welcomed.

Code/What I Tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json

# Load the data
file_name = "path/to/json/file"
with open(file_name) as fh:
    full_data = json.load(fh)

screen_shots = full_data['tabs'][0]['views'][3]['screenshots']

for number, screen_shot in enumerate(screen_shots):
    new_url = input("Screnshot URL: ").strip()

    str = """{
        "class" : "DepictionScreenshotsView"
    }"""
    data = json.loads(str)
    data["class"] = "test"

    full_data['tabs'][0]['views'][3]['screenshots'] = screen_shots

with open(file_name, 'w') as fh:
    json.dump(full_data, fh, indent=4)
```

JSON File:

```
{
   "minVersion": "1",
   "class": "DepictionTabView",
   "tintColor": "",
   "headerImage": "",
   "tabs": [
      {
         "tabname": "Details",
         "class": "DepictionStackView",
         "tintColor": "",
         "views": [
            {
               "class": "DepictionSubheaderView",
               "useBoldText": true,
               "useBottomMargin": false,
               "title": "Description"
            },
            {
               "class": "DepictionMarkdownView",
               "markdown": "Some dummy text...",
               "useRawFormat": true
            },
            {
               "class": "DepictionSeparatorView"
            },
            {
               "class": "DepictionSubheaderView",
               "useBoldText": true,
               "useBottomMargin": false,
               "title": "Screenshots"
            },
            {
               "class": "DepictionScreenshotsView",
               "itemCornerRadius": 6,
               "itemSize": "{160, 284.44444444444}",
               "screenshots": [
                  {
                     "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
                     "url": "http://example.com/image.png"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "class": "DepictionSeparatorView"
            },
            {
               "class": "DepictionSubheaderView",
               "useBoldText": true,
               "useBottomMargin": false,
               "title": "Information"
            },
            {
               "class": "DepictionTableTextView",
               "title": "Author",
               "text": "User"
            },
            {
               "class": "DepictionSpacerView",
               "spacing": 16
            },
            {
               "class": "DepictionStackView",
               "views": [
                  {
                     "class": "DepictionTableButtonView",
                     "title": "Contact",
                     "action": "http://example.com/",
                     "openExternal": true
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "class": "DepictionSpacerView",
               "spacing": 16
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "tabname": "History",
         "class": "DepictionStackView",
         "views": [
            {
               "class": "DepictionSubheaderView",
               "useBoldText": true,
               "useBottomMargin": false,
               "title": ""
            },
            {
               "class": "DepictionMarkdownView",
               "markdown": "",
               "useRawFormat": true
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Edit: I also tried this code but no luck (btw this is just a snipped of my code and not the full code)

```
import json

# Load the data
file_name = "path/to/json/file"
with open(file_name) as fh:
    full_data = json.load(fh)

    for tab in full_data.get('tabs', []):
        for view in full_data.get('views', []):
            if view.get('class') == 'DepictionScreenshotsView':
                view['class'] = ''

with open(file_name, 'w') as fh:
    json.dump(full_data, fh, indent=4)
```

Comment: Do you care about preserving the formatting of the json? The simplest way using the `json` library will most likely reorder the document and write it back out as a single line.

Comment: I would prefer to preserve the format if I can

Comment: @PeterGibson `json.dump` with the `indent` kwarg will dump to the file with newlines and indents

Comment: @Unknown what didn't work regarding the code you've posted? Was there an error?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
    full_data = json.load(fh)
    * More errors here to long to list all *
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Ok, so there's a reason I put `/path/to/newfile.json`, as opening a file in `w` mode will clear the contents of an existing file, and create the file if it doesn't exist. Check the contents of that `json` file that you're reading from

Comment: Is there any way I can keep them the same? Like use the same file for both the read and write file?

Comment: You could, but for debugging purposes, I would leave them separate until you are confident that bad data won't overwrite your file

Comment: My scripts creates a copy so it will be fine and I also have a backup self. How could I do this tho? Thanks

Comment: Deleting content (in a way that doesn't improve the site as a whole), even if it's content you added, is considered vandalism and against the rules. When you submit content to the site, you're giving the site a perpetual license to share it; when you delete that content, you're hurting both other people who could be helped by your question, and the people who worked to build answers.

Comment: The delete button is next to the edit button btw, to properly delete stuff.

Comment: @Max, ...notably, that button isn't always present -- if there are upvoted answers, f/e, it won't be available to a low-rep user who asked a question that hasn't been substantially downvoted.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ah my bad, didn't know, thanks

Comment: (There's a history of problems with users who asked questions that stemmed from school assignments then deleting the question as soon as they get a good answer to hide that they got outside assistance -- meaning that the answerer doesn't get to keep any rep they earned, and other folks with the same problem don't benefit; not saying that that's what happened here, but it's part of *why* we don't allow otherwise-good content to be deleted).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you should be able to just loop into the nested elements to find what you want:

```py
import json

with open("/path/to/file.json") as fh:
    content = json.load(fh)

# The second arg in get is the return in case the key isn't there
# and returning empty list will prevent errors saying NoneType isn't iterable
for tab in content.get('tabs', []):
    for view in content.get('views', []):
        if view.get('class') == 'DepictionScreenshotsView':
            view['class'] = ''

# This modifies content in place

with open('/path/to/newfile.json', 'w') as fh:
    json.dump(content, fh, indent=4)
```

Which will give:

```
{
    "minVersion": "1",
    "class": "DepictionTabView",
    "tintColor": "",
    "headerImage": "",
    "tabs": [
        {
            "tabname": "Details",
            "class": "DepictionStackView",
            "tintColor": "",
            "views": [
                {
                    "class": "DepictionSubheaderView",
                    "useBoldText": true,
                    "useBottomMargin": false,
                    "title": "Description"
                },
                {
                    "class": "DepictionMarkdownView",
                    "markdown": "Some dummy text...",
                    "useRawFormat": true
                },
                {
                    "class": "DepictionSeparatorView"
                },
                {
                    "class": "DepictionSubheaderView",
                    "useBoldText": true,
                    "useBottomMargin": false,
                    "title": "Screenshots"
                },
                {
                    "class": "",
                    "itemCornerRadius": 6,
                    "itemSize": "{160, 284.44444444444}",
                    "screenshots": [
                        {
                            "accessibilityText": "Screenshot",
                            "url": "http://example.com/image.png"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "class": "DepictionSeparatorView"
                },
                {
                    "class": "DepictionSubheaderView",
                    "useBoldText": true,
                    "useBottomMargin": false,
                    "title": "Information"
                },
                {
                    "class": "DepictionTableTextView",
                    "title": "Author",
                    "text": "User"
                },
                {
                    "class": "DepictionSpacerView",
                    "spacing": 16
                },
                {
                    "class": "DepictionStackView",
                    "views": [
                        {
                            "class": "DepictionTableButtonView",
                            "title": "Contact",
                            "action": "http://example.com/",
                            "openExternal": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "class": "DepictionSpacerView",
                    "spacing": 16
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "tabname": "History",
            "class": "DepictionStackView",
            "views": [
                {
                    "class": "DepictionSubheaderView",
                    "useBoldText": true,
                    "useBottomMargin": false,
                    "title": ""
                },
                {
                    "class": "DepictionMarkdownView",
                    "markdown": "",
                    "useRawFormat": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It also looks like the order is preserved, though I can't say if that's a guarantee, as I've never paid attention to that behavior before

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working this is the code: https://pastebin.com/yLi115pS (code is just a little snipped and no way my full code)

Comment: I can't reach that site